# Strange Error in XCode - Build Problems

Tags: xcode

I'm having an error that always appear when i build the code.

Here a screenshot of it:

http://d.pr/i/ifpB

What can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have source files called EXERCICI01 and EXERCICI02 in the same project.  Each of these defines a function called 'main'.  You are trying to link both of them into one target and that's not allowed.

Comment: Thank you very much, Phillip. I thought that I can have multiple unlinked files in just one project, but I will fix this.

Comment: You can do it if you define different targets inside your project and then select which files should belong to which targets.  (...making sure to **exclude** the ones with duplicate symbols.)

Comment: For selecting those files, you only need to drag and drop in the correct target?

Comment: Not sure...I haven't tried that.  Two other ways are: select the file, open the File Inspector view, and click the Target Membership check boxes; or select the target, go to the Build Phases tab, and add or remove files from the Compile phase.